# document.execCommand("copy") not working on all browser

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input id="test" value="Test" disabled />
<a onclick="copy()">Button</a>

function copy(){
   var text = document.getElementById("test");

   text.select();
   document.execCommand("copy");

   console.log("Copied the text: " + text.value);
}
```

I have above function to copy my copy. But its not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens instead? if you know already that **some** browsers cannot handle that code properly, which are those?

Comment: The clipboard API is not available in all browsers, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard

Comment: @Connum what would be to best solution to copy in all browser?

Comment: This SO should be linked here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421025/document-execcommandcopy-not-copying
And also the best example of a complete working example that works on all devices is at: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp  It includes the import method that must be called for execCommand("copy") to work on mobile devices.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few issues with your code:

- `disable` attribute on the input has to actually be `disabled`
- when you set `disabled` on the input, you cannot select its text in order to copy it, so you might either want to use `readonly` in this case or set `text.value` manually via `navigator.clipboard.writeText(text.value)`
- The Clipboard API is not available in all browsers, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard. For a long time, people used Flash for clipboard operations, but with Flash support being removed from browsers, there are not any options left. However, there are libraries like [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) that streamline clipboard operations across supported browsers.

```js
function copy(){
   var text = document.getElementById("test");

   // set arbitrary value instead of current selection
   // to clipboard to make it work with a disabled input as well
   navigator.clipboard.writeText(text.value);

   // text.select();   
   //document.execCommand("copy");

   console.log("Copied the text: " + text.value);
}

function copy2(){
   var text = document.getElementById("test2");

   text.select();   
   document.execCommand("copy");

   console.log("Copied the text: " + text.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="test" value="Test" disabled />
<a onclick="copy()">Button</a>
<hr>
<h3>using <code>document.execCommand("copy")</code></h3>
<input id="test2" value="Test2" readonly />
<a onclick="copy2()">Button</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. 'navigator.clipboard.writeText(text.value);` part of the code, does not work in all browser as well.

Comment: Correct, that's why libraries like the mentioned clipboard.js do all the work to make things consistent across different browser implementation. My code works in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Edge and possibly others.

Comment: `document.execCommand("copy");` used to work in chrome, but suddenly its not working. I am trying to find the solution to that.

Comment: I updated my answer to showcase the use of `execCommand("copy")`. This is also working in Chrome (with `readonly` instead of `disabled`, as mentioned in the answer). If it did work with `disabled` in Chrome before and now it doesn't, there's not much you can do if you don't like the other approach, except filing a bug report with Google/Chromium.

Comment: I have updated to use clipboardjs. But the copy function does not work on popup window.

Comment: It should work in a popup as well. If it doesn't, you're doing something right. Also, that's now a new issue and should be put into a new question with the code demonstrating the issue. Extending your original question with follow-ups after it has been answered, instead of marking the provided answer as accepted is actually not very nice...

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) library. It has a great browser support.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Please provide an example on how to use this library achieve the goals in the question